# VB.NET connection string retains old value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I have an asp.net website that uses VB.net code behind for some advanced functionality.  Recently I had to change the connection string from the newer access database type to an older version (ACCDB to MDB) due to incompatibility issue with my upgraded office 2016 64-bit office install.  Remapping my asp.net page tables worked without issue however when i change the vb code and run the project it errors out looking for the old database file.  I have searched the code and replaced every reference to the old database file yet it still tries to connect to it.  Please see the attached screenshot that illustrates this issue.

[image: Mapping Issue]

Comment: This is one of several reasons MS still recommends most people should install 32-bit Office, even on 64-bit workstations.

Comment: Yikes! Now that I can see the code image, it shows a HUGE sql injection security issue. This code is practically begging to get hacked. Also, we don't like images of code here. It makes it harder for us to help you, and therefore less likely you will get any help. Please paste the code into the question and use the code button on the editor so it's formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved.  Evidently you have to replace this value on all pages in your asp.net project.

Comment: You might want to consider using web.config to store the connection string in just one location so that it is easy to update. E.g. [Store Connection String in Web.config](https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/).

Comment: Yes!  Thank You!

Comment: Another thing to seriously consider is using [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) instead of Access - it is free (check the licence conditions, of course) and it is much better at being a multi-user database. It can be used as the back-end for an Access front-end with forms and stuff in a desktop environment.